# Change Data Capture in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database I want to track the value of a column  whenever it is changed .In a way such that every time value of a field changes we can know what was the previous value .It would be awesome to assign timestamps to each change.I am using MySQL as the database server.

Answer (score 11):

I recommend you take a look at [Debezium](http://debezium.io/) an open-source CDC platform which, amongst others, also [supports MySQL](http://debezium.io/docs/connectors/mysql/).

You can use Debezium to stream changes into Apache Kafka, but by means of its [embedded mode](http://debezium.io/docs/embedded/) you can also use the Debezium connectors as a library in your Java applications and easily propagate data changes to other streaming APIs such as Kinesis etc.

Disclaimer: I'm the Debezium project lead.

Answer (score 7):

To do that you need to create a trigger, which is an event that is fired when an `INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE` occurs on a given table.

Look at the documentation for [CREATE TRIGGER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html).

For what you want to do, you probably need to have an auxiliary table that has a row inserted for each `INSERT/UPDATE` on the main table, `AFTER` it happens containing the ID of the row changed, the old value the new value and a timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the very late answer, I would like to mention an other tool that hasn't been invoked in the other answer [maxwell](https://github.com/zendesk/maxwell) it's a CDC that reads the binlogs and sends messages on Kafka. The big advantage to this solution is the fact that it doesn't require any change to MySQL servers (no triggers to create ..).

Answer (score 1):

Triggers are not always the best way to record change events in database. As triggers can get invalidated once the schema of table changes, and it would in turn cause the actual table operation to fail.

For mysql, you need to capture the change events from binary log file. Mysql provides API to read binary log ( post version 5.6).

You may also want to look into [Flexviews](https://code.google.com/p/flexviews/) , which provides Oracle like Materialized View logs to record the change events.

Answer (score 1):

I created a tool called [cdc_audit](https://github.com/dan-da/cdc_audit) that automates creation of audit tables in mysql for any or all tables, and even preserves pre-existing triggers.  I wrote it with change data capture (for data warehouse ETL applications) in mind.  Maybe you or someone will find it useful.

I also [blogged about it](http://osc.co.cr/automate-mysql-audit-tables-with-cdc_audit-auto-generate-populate-and-sync/).

Features

- automates generation of audit tables
- automates generation of triggers to populate audit tables
- automates syncing of new rows in audit tables to .csv files.
- Reads mysql information_schema to automatically determine tables and columns.
- Can generate tables + triggers for all database tables, or a specified list.
- Can sync audit tables for all database tables, or a specified list.
- Retains pre-existing trigger logic, if any, when generating AFTER triggers.
- sync script option to delete all but last audit row, to keep source DB small.

Comment: The link to your blog is broken.