# Save Database field changes - best practices? Versioning, Loggable?

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine

i am using Symfony 2 with Doctrine as ORM Framework. I am searching for the best way to save changes done to database fields. I will have about 100 Tables each with about 50 fields and some thousand rows. Now i would like to save all changes done to the fields.

Possibilities i thought about:
Doctrine extension "Loggable" - saves changes in a different Table, but don't know if it can afford this amount of entries.

a MySQL Trigger for each Table that saves changes in a new Table?

But what is the best practice to save changes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use either MySQL triggers or the mentioned DoctrineExtension Loggable feature. Both works, both has cons and pros. MySQL trigger can write into a separate table (see [mysql trigger FAQ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/faqs-triggers.html#qandaitem-B-5-1-9)).

triggers:

- ++ framework, programming language independent
- ++ works when you want to modify the data by hand or by a script.
- -- You have to write the triggers for every table or have to figure out some generic solution in SQL (I can't help on that).
- -- If you are not familiar with stored procedures and PL/SQL, well, there is learning curve

doctrine extensions:

- ++ Just put your annotation on classes and you're done.
- ++ You can query the history, revert changes through the Repository API
- -- you lock yourself to a vendor, this sometimes is, sometimes isn't a problem
- -- doesn't works when you modify the data by hand or with a 3rd party scripts.

If the chance of switching doctrine to something else is low, I would start with doctrine extensions. It's a tool with the exact purpose to help dealing with SQL after all.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest going with triggers, especially if you want your logging functionality to stay application independent — that is, it will work even if you decide to rewrite your app on a different framework or completely different programming language.

P.S. I don't know how great is triggers support in MySQL, since I switched to PostgreSQL before MySQL even had them.

Answer (score 0):

Such a thing is commonly called "change data capture".  It's been asked about with reference to MySQL before on SO:

[Change Data Capture in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394359/change-data-capture-in-mysql)

Maybe this answer can help you.

Different vendors make this a built in feature to varying degrees.

Comment: I'll try to improve on it.  Certainly the "change data capture" phrase is worth it alone, since the OP can take that and run with it.

Answer (score 0):

The following article has a step by step explanation + sample code of doing versioning using triggers.

http://www.jasny.net/articles/versioning-mysql-data/